# Stop Icon from changing at the same time in Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a list of an icon in a table, and when the icon is clicked, the whole list of icons changed to the other icon. How should I stop them from changing at the same time?

Code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles, Theme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import FilterListIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorderOutlined';
import FavoriteOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FavoriteOutlined';
...

export default function Table() {
    ...
        const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = React.useState(false);
    ...
    return (
        ...
                                    return (
                                        <TableRow
                                            hover
                                            tabIndex={-1}
                                            key={row.name}>
                                            <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
                                            ...
                                            <TableCell>
                                                    <IconButton onClick={() => setIsFavorite(!isFavorite)}>
                                                        {isFavorite ? <FavoriteOutlinedIcon color="secondary"/> :  <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon color="action"/> }
                                                    </IconButton>
                                            </TableCell>
                                               ...
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you upload your code to codesandbox?

Comment: You need to provide more context and cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state isFavorite is being toggle with every click. To get the functionality you want, you'll need to have a favorite property on an icon object. Here's an example:

```
const [iconData, setIconData] = useState([
  {icon: someIcon, id: 1, isFavorite: false},
  {icon: diffIcon, id: 2, isFavorite: false},
  {icon: thirdIcon, id: 3, isFavorite: false}
])
```

In the return statement, you'll want to map over the iconData

```
iconData.map(icon => (
<TableCell key={icon.id}>
    <IconButton onClick={() => iconFavChange(icon.id)}>
      {icon.isFavorite ? <FavoriteOutlinedIcon color="secondary"/> :  
           <FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon color="action"/> }
     </IconButton>
</TableCell>
))
```

Handle Icon change

```
const iconFavChange =(id)=> {
 let updatedIconData = iconData.map(icon => icon.id === id ? icon.isFavorite = !icon.isFavorite : icon)
// map over existing state data and if the id in args matches id of icon,
//then toggle the isFavorite property
 setIconData(updatedIconData)
}
```

Edit:

1. You row data was saved in a constant outside component. I added a slice of state and set row as the initial state.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState(rows);
```

2. I added an isFavorite property on your row data

```
isFavorite: boolean;
```

3. I added a favorite handler. It takes name as arg, loops over your data and toggles isFavorite property.

```
const handleFavoriteToggle = name => {
    console.log(name);
    let updatedData = data.map(row => {
      if (row.name === name) {
        row.isFavorite = !row.isFavorite;
      }
      return row;
    });
    setData(updatedData);
  };
```

4. Updated the icon component

```
<IconButton onClick={() => handleFavoriteToggle(row.name)}>
    {row.isFavorite ? (<FavoriteOutlinedIcon color="secondary" />)
                    : (<FavoriteBorderOutlinedIcon color="action" />)}
</IconButton>
```

5. Changed param from row to our data slice of state

```
<TableBody>
            {stableSort(data, getComparator(order, orderBy))
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((row, index) => {
```

Comment: They still change at the same time, I'm not sure what I did wrong. Now I'm trying to set each cell to have its own state, but I'm not sure how to customize the TableCell Component in Material-UI...

Comment: @Zonaahmmm can you add your code to codesandbox please

Comment: Sorry I'm new to codesandbox. Does this work? https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-worker-tvjsi?file=/src/course.tsx

Comment: @Zonaahmmm yes, but it looks like you may have forgotten to save because one of the files is empty.

Comment: @Zonaahmmm yes, take a look at my fork. Explanation above in edit.

Comment: codesandbox fork https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-bash-g9k5y?file=/src/course.tsx:983-1003